# How can I post stories to Facebook from web instead of Android and iOS Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm quite new to Facebook Graph API but I got a question on how to post stories to Facebook from web application using Graph API.

Based on [Facebook - Sharing to Stories](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/sharing-to-stories)they only explain a ways to post stories from Android and iOS application but not from Web application, is there any possible way to publish a stories to Facebook from web thru Graph API or any other Facebook's API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found the answer, based on my research across the official documentation and other places on the web.

I'm convinced that there's no way to publish a Facebook Story thru a web application, this is because as of right now, Facebook API only supports the ability to publish stories on Android or iOS environments only and not the web application, but correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I'm also thinking the same